# SSMS messages tab auto-scroll

Tags: scroll, ssms, message, autoscroll

This is a question about SSMS rather than SQL.

I am running a loop that is constantly giving me the number of rows affected in the messages tab of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. It fills up the whole page every second, so I have to scroll down manually to keep up with what is going on.

Is there a setting (similar to "Scroll as results are received" in the results tab) to scroll as messages are received in the messages tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This one is a bit old, but found myself with a similar situation. If you change the output to "Results to Text", the messages are displayed and scrolled per the option at Tools->Options-SQL Server-Results To Text:Scroll as results are received.

Comment: I have this option enable but for some reason the "Messages" doesn't scrolled.

Comment: This setting is about the results tab, not the messages tab.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an auto-scroll, but if the cursor is in the Messages window then Ctrl-End on the keyboard should take you to the bottom of the output.